# how to rerender a fullcalendar component in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, fullcalendar

i'm using fullCalendar library for vuejs and i need to refresh  the component when i delete an event

```
<div>
    <FullCalendar :key="componentKey" v-model="FullCalendar"
      locale="es"
      :plugins="calendarPlugins"
      :header="{
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev today next'
      }"
      :buttonText="{
        today: $t('today')
      }"
      :events="EVENTS"
      :selectable="true"
      :editable="false"
      @select="handleSelect"
      @eventClick="handleEventClick"
    />
  </div>
```

i've tried with key for refresh component using watch and mounted but both are useless, the component doesn't refresh, it's only happening when i try to delete an event

```
handleEventClick (arg) {
      request.post('api/festivities/show', {day: arg.event._instance.range.start, name: arg.event._def.title})
        .then(res => {
          Swal({
            position: 'top-end',
            title: res.data.name,
            html: 'information',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Eliminar'
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result === true) {
              request.post('api/festivities/delete', {day: arg.event._instance.range.start, name: arg.event._def.title})
                .then(answer => {
                  //this part should reset the component
                  //the best i could do is this line that reset the browser
                  this.$router.go()
                })
            }
          })
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          this.$spinner.close()
        })
    }
```

the only thing that i've been able to do is to refresh the route. actually the event is been deleted from DB but persist in the view

Comment: You can load the events again.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the component to rerender by giving a :key property and update it every time when you want the component to be rebuilt.

In your case, you have to change componentKey at that place

```
if (result === true) {
              request.post('api/festivities/delete', {day: arg.event._instance.range.start, name: arg.event._def.title})
                .then(answer => {
                  this.componentKey++;
                  this.$router.go()
                })
          }
```

Comment: i already tried, it doesn't work,i think it's because it doesn't modify the childs. i had to find and modify manually the event

Comment: Could you expand on what specifically you did? When I update the key, the entire calendar disappears @JorgeNicolasOrtizGualteros